# MySQL - Calling stored procedure each time with parameters from result rows of cursor

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I have the below procedure in MySQLWorkbench, in which i have one select query with 2 columns (col1 and col2), it  fetches multiple rows,
for each rows found i need to execute another procedure passing col1 and col2.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE newproc()
BEGIN

    declare @field1 varchar(30);
    declare @field2 varchar(30);

    declare cur CURSOR  for Select col1, col2 from RG ;

    open cur;

    fetch  next  cur into @field1, @field2;

    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN

        exec another_proc @field1, @field2

        fetch next from cur into @field1, @field2
    END

    close cur
    deallocate cur

END
```

I am getting this error at this line

```
declare @field1 varchar(30);
```

> Syntax error: unexpected '@field1' at text suffix

Can someone help me with this ti fix the code?

Comment: Help you with what? What is your question? Does this code work? Does it not produce the results you want? What did you want to happen and what happened instead.

Comment: #Am getting this error at this line declare @field1 varchar(30);                Syntax error: unexpected '@field1' at text suffix)

Comment: You are using Transact-SQL syntax (Microsoft SQL Server). Check: [9.4 User-Defined Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html), [13.6.4 Variables in Stored Programs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-variables.html) and [13.6.6 Cursors](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html).